# Prevent custom Ribbon button from redirecting to new item

Tags: content-editor, ribbon

I have created a custom Ribbon button that creates a new item. However, when clicking this button the Content Editor switches over to this new item, whereas I expected it to stay on the first item.

Why is it doing this, and how can I prevent this?

For those wondering, this is how I'm creating item from the custom button, with a complete (simplified) `Command` implementation:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyCustomCommand : Command {

    public override void Execute(CommandContext context) {

        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context, "context");
        if (!context.Items.Any())
        {
            return;
        }
        Item item = context.Items[0];

        using (new SecurityDisabler()) {
            Item newItem = GetParentItem(item).Add("New Name", templateItem);
            try {
                newItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
                newItem["Foo"] = "Bar";
                newItem.Editing.EndEdit();
            } catch (Exception) {
                newItem?.Editing.CancelEdit();
            }
        }
    }

    public override CommandState QueryState(CommandContext context)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context, "context");

        if (!context.Items.Any())
        {
            return CommandState.Disabled;
        }

        // Various enabled/disabled check

        return CommandState.Enabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the whole code of your button class?

Comment: This post should help you with selecting the correct item. Before adding the new one I would get the ID of the current item and follow the example in the link.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385543/how-to-select-item-in-sitecore-content-editor

Comment: @MarekMusielak Whole code of button class added

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by introducing Progress Window.

Break your Execute method into two separate methods like below.

**Execute** method:

```
public override void Execute(CommandContext context) {

    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context, "context");
    if (!context.Items.Any())
    {
        return;
    }
    Item item = context.Items[0];

    try
    {
        ProgressBox.Execute(
             "Creating New Item", 
             "Title",
             "Applications/32x32/refresh.png",
             CreateItem,
             new object[] { templateItem }));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Error!", ex, this);
    }        
}
```

**CreateItem** method:

```
public void CreateItem(params object[] parameters) {

    using (new SecurityDisabler()) {
        Item newItem = GetParentItem(item).Add("New Name", templateItem);
        try {
            newItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
            newItem["Foo"] = "Bar";
            newItem.Editing.EndEdit();
        } 
        catch (Exception)
        {
            newItem?.Editing.CancelEdit();
        }
    }

    ///other custom logic
}
```

If you wish to show some message window after creation, take a look in this thread: [In the Content Editor, how can I have a Sitecore alert popup code run after the ProgressBox Execute code has finished running?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5034/in-the-content-editor-how-can-i-have-a-sitecore-alert-popup-code-run-after-the)

Comment: This works, but do you know why Content Editor redirects to new items created without using `ProgressBox`?

Comment: It is the standard behaviour as you are working with different Context Item to currently selected one